# Причастный оборот

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая перед словом НЕТ? Умом понимаю, что кажется нет, но не смогла найти правило, которое здесь применяется.

Никаких дополнительных нормативно-правовых документов, устанавливающих требования к устройству оборудования НЕТ.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, нужна. В чистом виде причастный оборот после определяемого слова.

Заскок-с? )))

Comment: Заскок-с, заскок-с.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение надо переделать, так как оборот требует обязательного обособления:

(1) Нет никаких дополнительных нормативно-правовых документов, устанавливающих требования к устройству оборудования.

(2) Никаких дополнительных нормативно-правовых документов, устанавливающих требования к устройству оборудования, не существует.

Comment: >> Предложение надо переделать, так как оборот требует обязательного обособления

Почему переделать?
Второй ваш вариант совсем плох, так в документах не пишут. Да и первый хуже оригинала.

Comment: Мне оба варианта нравятся, но я вообще не склонна переделывать авторские тексты, поэтому переделывать скорее всего не буду. А вот наличие запятой смущает. Как-то не смотрится...

Comment: Такое предложение не только не смотрится, но и не читается. При прочтении приходится слово "нет" включать в оборот, при визуальном восприятии делается то же самое, что затрудняет понимание предложения.

Comment: Здесь дело в не том, что оборот неудачен с стилистической точки зрения, а в том, требуется ли запятая в самом обороте. Зачем переделывать оборот? Запятая нужна, и это все подтвердили.